# Code example of the fleury or hierholzer algorithm?

Tags: php, algorithm, graph

I'm looking for an code example of the Fleury or Hierholzer algorithm. I couldn't find any in my language?

Comment: > I can offer other PHP scripts. - hahahaha

Comment: That's very sweet. Why not code it yourself? We'll help you! (edit: Hmm, I would have expected it would be easier to find this online though. Nice to know for CS teachers, I guess)

Comment: Code is not currency here. This site is designed for free Q&A. If what you're asking is beyond what people can be expected to give out simple good will, then this isn't the place for it :)

Comment: @Will I don't think he is asking for someone to spend their entire night / day writing code. I think he is looking for someone with an on hand reference that would be nice enough to help him out by referring him / her to the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a decent code in pascal http://linhtruong.com/Blog/index.php?page=fleury-algorithm---find-euler-circuit but I wonder how it works? My php code is something else.